# React Query - Can't pass proper arguments to mutationFn

Tags: react-query

I have a mutation function that looks like this:

```
  const {mutate: comentarMutation, isPending: comentarLoading} =
useMutation<ComentarioValoracionInterface>({
  mutationFn: () =>
    comentarValoracion(currentCommentScreenItem!, {texto: inputText}),
  onMutate: () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  },
  onSuccess: response => {
    setInputText('');
    queryClient.setQueryData(
      [QueryKeys.COMENTARIOS_VALORACION, currentCommentScreenItem!],
      (oldData: any) => {
        const newData = oldData;
        newData.pages[0].unshift(response);
        return newData;
      },
    );
  },
});
```

It works, because I put the arguments of the functions directly inside it, instead of passing them on the call of the mutate function.

But, what I would want to do is this:

```
mutationFn: (id: string, params: {texto: string}) =>
    comentarValoracion(id!, params),
```

However, I can't do it because I keep getting type errors like this:

*Type '(id: string, params: {    texto: string;}) => Promise' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<ComentarioValoracionInterface, void>'.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.*

I tried many things: Making it an object, passing it without types... nothing worked so far and I want to understand if that is possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue and was able to resolve it after passing the variables as object. (Mentioned here https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/1216#discussioncomment-162825)

In your case, try the following (not tested)

```
const handleComentar = ({id, params:{texto: inputText}}:{id: string, params: any}) => comentarValoracion(id, params)

const {mutate: comentarMutation, isPending: comentarLoading} =
useMutation<ComentarioValoracionInterface>({
  mutationFn: handleComentar,
  onMutate: () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  },
  onSuccess: response => {
    setInputText('');
    queryClient.setQueryData(
      [QueryKeys.COMENTARIOS_VALORACION, currentCommentScreenItem!],
      (oldData: any) => {
        const newData = oldData;
        newData.pages[0].unshift(response);
        return newData;
      },
    );
  },
});
```